How to print directly in CMYK with a HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M176n printer?
I have an HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M176n printer. I replaced the black toner with a white toner cartridge in order to be able to print white on black paper.
Printing in grayscale seems to work okay, and I'm now looking into also printing colors. For that I would need to tell the printer to use both a color toner and black toner in the same area. I can do that in the drawing software by setting, for example the C and K values to 100%. The problem is that all of the available printer color profiles appear to be RGB, so the colors are converted after being sent and the resulting color mostly only uses the K toner.
Is there a way to bypass this conversion and set CMYK values directly?

Normally this would be something in the printer, and you may be able to add a color profile in control panel, display.
